# Can we have in-place editing in /review?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, review, inline-editor

A lot of what comes through /review is actually good content, but more often than not it's in need of editing. It would make this process much easier if it could be done in place. Currently you're taken to the question page, and when you've finished editing you remain there, meaning you have to go back twice to get to /review. Eliminating this would make editing much less of a chore.

Comment: Agreed. Often when reviewing first answers, the grammar and/or lack of capitalization is atrocious. I'd like to be able to fix these bits more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why **YES** ... you can have it in `/review` and the `10k flag review tools`

Enjoy

Comment: This is pretty awesome :) , what is a _little_ annoying is, after I finish editing, I'm brought back to the question page, and I expect to go back to the review page. So what I end up doing in usually `Ctrl + Click` edit and it opens in a new tab, I finish the edit, and then I can still go and continue where I left off in the review page.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, in most cases I like to have a look at the complete page (question, answers and comments) before starting to edit a question or answer.

The "need two clicks to go back" might need some improvement, but I'm not sure inline-editing is the way to go here.

Comment: I can see that would be a good thing, returning to /review after saving the edit would be hugely helpful though.

Comment: As @PengOne pointed out, it's usually not the kind of edit where I need to see the whole question, it's formatting, spelling, removal of sign-offs, exclamation marks etc. This kind of editing can be done without seeing the question, and being able to do it efficiently would mean I'd do a lot more of it.

Comment: I usually go by "improve everything which can be improved, if I'm already editing" ... and this needs looking at the question, too. Your mileage may vary, though.